# Pintool: Detect and Bypass Non Deterministic system calls

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, non-deterministic

I am trying to write a Pintool that can perform record and replay functionality. So the problem statement is to detect all non-deterministic system calls and record all its arguments and then perform replay with the original arguments while bypassing the system call. The problem is that I have a list of system calls that are relevant to my program (around 22 of them) and I need to know which of these are non-deterministic and deterministic calls.

The list is as following : with Call Number

[image]